# CDK Virtual Scroll for Angular Material Table not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, pagination, angular-cdk-virtual-scroll

I have an angular material table that has millions of records, I have added pagination which has options like 10, 25, 50, 100, 500, and 1000, and the max length of the records, which I select 1000 or max records option, there's a delay in the change of options in pagination also when I scroll the table, there's a second delay in loading data to the table on scroll. To make the scroll smooth & records load faster, I thought of having a CDK virtual scroll for the table.

I have added the scroll, but the table is not loading, below is my code

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="50">
            <table mat-table fixedLayout [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows matSort
                (matSortChange)="sortData($event)" #sort="matSort" matSortStart="desc">
                <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns;" [matColumnDef]="column.columnDef">
                    <ng-container>
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{column.header}} </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                            {{element[column.columnDef]}}
                        </td>
                    </ng-container>
            ................
                </ng-container>
                <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
                <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
                <tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
                    <td class="mat-cell" colspan="4">No records found.</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
        <mat-paginator #paginator="matPaginator" [pageSizeOptions]="pageSizeOptions"
            showFirstLastButtons (page)="onPaginateChange($event)">
        </mat-paginator>
```

I have tried replacing *ngFor with *cdkVirtualFor which isn't working too. Any help is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have not added the height and use `*cdkVirtualFor` instead of `*ngFor`

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="50" style="height:500px;">
            <table mat-table fixedLayout [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows matSort
                (matSortChange)="sortData($event)" #sort="matSort" matSortStart="desc">
                <ng-container *cdkVirtualFor="let column of columns;" [matColumnDef]="column.columnDef">
                    <ng-container>
                        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{column.header}} </th>
                        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                            {{element[column.columnDef]}}
                        </td>
                    </ng-container>
            ................
                </ng-container>
                <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
                <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
                <tr class="mat-row" *matNoDataRow>
                    <td class="mat-cell" colspan="4">No records found.</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

Comment: thank you it's working now but the existing pagination options are not displaying after this change

Comment: It should be there. Inspect the browser and select inspect element. Then search for the pagination options.

Comment: as itemSize is added, it's by default showing only 50records per page, and option to change pagination is not displaying, any way to enable it?

Comment: This answer is not related to virtual rendering of records. You are virtually instantiating columns, but this does not resolve problem with slow rendering of 'millions of records'.

Answer (score 0):

`mat-table` does not render rows with virtual scroll (yet). But you can build basic `<table>` inside `<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>` with `<tr *cdkVirtualFor>` and style it according to Material concept.

Comment: that is what I'm doing right, having mat-table inside cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport

Comment: how can I improve performance for rendering on pagination options change?

Comment: mat-table does not work with cdk-virtual-scroll but generic html <table> will. There is a feature request in github https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10122 with some workarounds that can be usable in some cases.

Comment: Fetching from server and buffering of millions of records will be slow anyway. May be loading in chunks with pagination is better idea.